# prepared statement returns an empty array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I cannot use `%s` in my prepared statement.

```
echo $get_where; // returns: edited = 1
$get_uncontacted_members = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE %s", $get_where)
);
```

This code returns an empty array. But when I use `$get_where` instead of `%s` (see code bellow), then it returns all the results from the database.

```
// This works
echo $get_where; // returns: edited = 1
$get_uncontacted_members = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE edited = 1", $get_where)
);
```

Why wouldn't it work with `%s`?

Comment: because `%s` is for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) and company, use `?` (at least i think thats right)

Comment: And `$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE edited = 1", $get_where)` won't do anything with `$get_where` because there's nothing to bind it to: it'll simply be ignored

Comment: @castis `?` also returns an empty array.

Comment: @MarkBaker I know that. I was only trying to say that when I use `edited = 1` instead of `%s`, I'll get my results. I didn't remove the `$get_where` on purpose, since it would cause an error then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress while uses the sprintf() syntax, it actually works like prepared statements. As such you can only pass the value of the column you are querying against, not entire column(s) and values.

```
$get_uncontacted_members = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE IFNULL(edited,'') = %s", 1)
);
```

Comment: Oh wow, that means I have a problem now. But thanks, good to know! The value of the variable `$get_where` could be either **edited = 1** or **edited IS NULL OR edited = ''** ... Any idea how I could reach my goal?

Comment: I updated my code so now your %s will always work basically NULL and '' will be the same thing now. So you can pass in the variable as either 1 or ''